# gnuplot error: `Image grid must be at least 2 x 2'

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with 5 columns of data in it. The first column are x indexes, the second are y indexes and the following three contain some data on which I perform some calculations in my gnuplot script as follows:

```
module(a,b,c) = sqrt(a**2+b**2+c**2);
splot 'myfile' using 1:2:(module($3,$4,$5)) with image
```

This works fine. However, if I try to plot the log10 of the module like this:

```
module(a,b,c) = log10(sqrt(a**2+b**2+c**2));
splot 'myfile' using 1:2:(module($3,$4,$5)) with image
```

it returns a blank plot and the warning of the title of the question.

I think it might be due to the zeros that are in my data, but even when I set an xy range to avoid those, the error persists.

Comment: Then please show us an examplary data file which allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It may be a bug. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/WJH9jFWOIB8